# Calling -[UIView layoutSubviews] during a custom animation like UIScrollView does

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

when UIScrollView is scrolling animated (e.g. with `setContentOffset:animated:`), it periodically calls its `layoutSubviews`, where subclasses can adjust the layout.

I now want to do something similar with a custom view and a custom animation (`+[UIView begin/commitAnimations]`). I know I can get the current bounds from the CAlayer's presentation layer, however I do not know how to hook into the animation to be able to periodically call layoutSubviews.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom view, can you overide setFrame like this ?

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)rect 
{
    [super setFrame:rect]
    [self layoutSubviews];
}
```